# hdiutil: attach failed - No such file or directory, in Maven Projects using AppleScript

Tags: maven, applescript

I am trying to mount the application which is present in a module named x. I am using Maven projects here, so for mounting the app I am using a shell script. I have given the path of the application which is present in module x. If I try to run the test from the class where this mounting method is present, it's being compiled and I am getting results properly, but when I use this mounting method in some other test class and ran the test, it's saying "no such file present" I know this looks strange, but I am facing this issue. Please tell me how to overcome this.

```
do shell script "hdiutil mount ../../common/src/main/resources/Modulex/AdbeRdr11000_en_US.dmg"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the above prob, just i need to change the path, since i was running the same test from testsuite.

do shell script "hdiutil mount ../common/src/main/resources/Modulex/AdbeRdr11000_en_US.dmg"